# How to load file from qrc in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

I want to load Icon from qrc . I have compiled my .qrc file by following command:-

```
pyrcc5 icon.qrc >> icon.py
```

But I have no idea how to load this image. In C++ , I would just call "qrc:/Icon.png"  . I had imported the icon.py file as [this tiny riverbank page without any example has told](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/resources.html) but in Python I have no idea

So far this is my main.py code :-

```
% cat main.py 
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import  QIcon
from calculator import Calculator
import icon

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = Calculator()
win.setWindowIcon(QIcon("qrc/Icon.png"))
win.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am using PyQt5 with Python3.6

Comment: show your .qrc, but in general you should import it with: `win.setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/Icon.png"))`

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks. it worked !! Thank you so much